# Python вычисление евклидова расстояния в большой базе

Tags: python

Собрал многомиллионную базу лиц с признаками 128 векторов. Для поиска похожих лиц использую векторы искомого лица вычисляя с каждой записью базы алгоритмом евклидова расстояния:

```
math.sqrt(pow(sv1 - v1, 2) + pow(sv2 - v2, 2) + ...[128 векторов])
```

> результат если меньше 0,6 значит похожее лицо. где sv - вектора
>   искомого лица, и v - вектора каждой записи из базы.

Т.к. для поиска требуется очень много вычислений, то это занимает довольно долгое время.
Какие есть варианты для скорости может быть нужно применить другой алгоритм и применить более дорогое железо то какое? Может на GPU, но я не сообразил как реализовать это.

Ваши догадки, как бы вы сделали. Приветствуется на любом языке.

Comment: [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/745545/211923)

Comment: Вычислять в БД, используя SPATIAL индекс? Используется в гео-поиске, может тут также подойдет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. В такой постановке задачи нет смысла в вычислении корня квадратного, выбросьте его и сравнивайте с `0.36`
2. В зависимости от наличия вычислительных ресурсов, размера и вида базы данных, стоит подумать о дальнейшей реализации. Нужно определить, какой процесс быстрее и насколько велика эта разница - получение 1000 векторов для обсчета или обсчет 1000 векторов.
3. Процессы загрузки и формирования потока данных и обсчета следует распараллелить. Пока обсчитывается очередная порция, можно потихоньку подгружать из базы следующий кусок.