# Поиск N-го количества ближайших точек

Tags: python, оптимизация

Имеется код по поиску 5 ближайших точек на сфере.

Возможно ли оптимизировать код?

Потому что на 10 тысячах процесс, хоть и долгий, но завершается. А на 35 тысячах уже не хватает памяти. Посоветуйте, возможно ли использование дополнительных модулей, чтобы избежать большого количества циклов.

```
from math import radians, cos, sin, asin, sqrt
import csv


def haversine(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):
    """
    Calculate the great circle distance between two points
    on the earth (specified in decimal degrees)
    """
    # convert decimal degrees to radians
    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])
    # haversine formula
    dlon = lon2 - lon1
    dlat = lat2 - lat1
    a = sin(dlat/2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon/2)**2
    c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a))
    # Radius of earth in kilometers is 6371
    km = 6371* c
    return km


with open('coordinates.csv', 'r',  encoding='utf-8') as w:
    d = dict()
    a = []
    for line in w:
        a.append(line.strip().split(';'))
for i in a:
    d[i[0]] = 0
    for j in a:
        if i[0] != j[0]:
            m = haversine(float(i[2]), float(i[1]), float(j[2]), float(j[1]))*1000
            if d[i[0]] == 0:
                d[i[0]] = {j[0]: m}
            else:
                d[i[0]][j[0]] = m

    # Сортируем словарь
    d[i[0]] = {k: v for k, v in sorted(d[i[0]].items(), key=lambda item: item[1])}  
    # Удаляем все точки начиная с 6-ой
    p = 0
    index_to_delete = range(5, 99999)
    keys_to_delete = set()
    for key in d[i[0]].keys():
        if p in index_to_delete:
            keys_to_delete.add(key)
        p += 1
    for key in keys_to_delete:
        if key in d[i[0]]:
            del d[i[0]][key]
    keys_to_delete.clear()

daf = []
for key, value in d.items():
    for g, v in value.items():
        daf.append([int(key), int(g), v])

with open('test111.csv', 'w') as f:
    wtr = csv.writer(f, delimiter=';', lineterminator="\r")
    wtr.writerows(daf)
```

Comment: Для 35000 точек нужно посчитать расстояния для ~612.5 миллионов пар точек. Сколько у вас доступной памяти??

Comment: Можно тут для начала почитать https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6656475/python-speeding-up-geographic-comparison

Comment: @MaxU порядка 12 Гб памяти свободно

Comment: @РавшанГайнулин, "не густо" для таких задач...

Comment: @MaxU Тот дубликат не годится, он предлагает оптимизацию брутфорса, в то время как существуют лучшие алгоритмы для ближайших точек, а не для расчёта всех пар

Comment: Да, сейчас полно библиотек для быстрого подсчёта расстояний "каждый с каждым", вот в этой вроде есть `haversine`, но какую лучше использовать для поиска N ближайших надо смотреть, разбираться. https://github.com/lmcinnes/pynndescent

Comment: @РавшанГайнулин, можете уточнить вопрос - вы хотите найти N ближайших точек от одной конкретной точки?

Comment: Обычно пользуются чем-то типа kdTree.

Comment: [связанный вопрос...](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/745492/211923)

Comment: @MaxU да, всё верно, от каждой точки до всех (ну кроме самой себя)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться одним из [алгоритмов NN (`"Nearest Neighbors"`)](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neighbors.html).

Пример для 2-х ближайших соседей

```
>>> from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
>>> import numpy as np
>>> X = np.array([[-1, -1], [-2, -1], [-3, -2], [1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 2]])
>>> nbrs = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=2, algorithm='ball_tree').fit(X)
>>> distances, indices = nbrs.kneighbors(X)
>>> indices
array([[0, 1],
       [1, 0],
       [2, 1],
       [3, 4],
       [4, 3],
       [5, 4]]...)
>>> distances
array([[0.        , 1.        ],
       [0.        , 1.        ],
       [0.        , 1.41421356],
       [0.        , 1.        ],
       [0.        , 1.        ],
       [0.        , 1.41421356]])
```

Comment: А не будет проблем с широтой или долготой при пересечении чего-нибудь там, они сплошные? А то может без подходящей метрики всё же нельзя?

Comment: @CrazyElf, можно указать `metric="euclidean"` - мне кажется для поиска ближайших точек на сфероиде она тоже подойдет

Comment: Вероятно, нужно `BallTree  metric='haversine'`

Comment: @MBo, да можно и так)

Comment: Спасибо всем за содействие, особенно @MaxU, с итоговой задачей разобрался.